# Is my intuition here regarding generic sets used in forcing correct?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

In Jech's Chapter 14, p. 218 (2nd edition), the proof for the generic model theorem (i.e. Theorem 14.5) begins with: *"Let $(P, <) $ be a notion of forcing in the ground model $M$, and let $G \subset P$ be generic over $M$"*.

Afterwards, the corresponding boolean algebra $B=B(P)$ is constructed (for which $P$ is dense), followed by the boolean-valued model $M^P$ and finally the generic extension $M[G]$ for which $G \in M[G]$.

But from what I understand, the generic set $G \subset P$ over $M$ may not necessarily exist, whereas the proof begins with the assumption that $G$ does exist.

But if $M$ was assumed to be countable, then $G$ could be shown to exist (there's a proof in Jech to show this). However, as the book says in its Introduction to Chapter 14, this route is not ideal since a countable model of ZFC may not be proven within ZFC due to Godel's incompleteness theorem. Therefore, as per the book, the modern approach is to "pretend" that $G$ holds in the universe and the whole chapter 14 of Jech seems to rely on this premise...

But am I right to think that the we can also use this route (following my understanding of Hamkins and Seabold's paper): Given that any forcing condition set $P$ has a Boolean completion $B$ for which it is dense, we can first construct the Boolean-valued model $M^B$. Then we can pick any ultrafilter $H$ in $B$ and construct the generic extension $M[H]$. The ultrafilter $H$ is  guaranteed to be related to some generic set $G$ such that their Boolean-valued models are equal, i.e. $M[G]=M[H]$, although we don't need to specify what $G$ is ...

Is my intuition correct or am I missing something here ? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Pretending that $G$ exists means adding an axiom to $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that asserts $G$'s existence for a cardinality $\kappa$ of a family $\mathcal D=\{D_i\}_{i\in\kappa}$ such that $\kappa>\aleph_0$.  It's called Martin's axiom $\text{MA}(\kappa)$.  $\text{MA}(2^{\aleph_0})$ is inconsistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$.  For $\aleph_0<\kappa<2^{\aleph_0}$, $\text{MA}(\kappa)$ is independent of $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Comment: The generic model theorem, as stated in Jech, is premised on the existence of a generic filter, i.e.. it's a statement of the form "for any generic filter $G$..."... so of course the proof starts "let $G$ be a generic filter". There is no assumption here that generics always exist here and this is quite orthogonal to the justification for the common practice of 'pretending' they do.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, okay thanks a lot ... so to make sure that (not necessarily countable) generic filters always exist as done in the common practice, there is some additional axiom that's needed ? (i.e. Martin's axiom - as pointed out in the comment above)

Comment: @LinkL There are different ways to justify it. You can either work explicitly with countable transitive models and then make some compactness arguments to patch up the consistency strength problem (a good reference for this is Kunen's book) or use a syntactical or Boolean-value model approach which doesn't require a generic filter, but one still has access to the canonical *name* for one, $\dot G= \{(\check p, p): p\in P\}$, and more generally we can use what's forced as a stand-in for what's true in $V[G].$ See also [Hamkins and Seabold](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.6075.pdf) section 4.

Comment: @LinkL A couple answers of mine along these lines (and I'm sure there's quite a few better answers from others elsewhere on the site) https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4735317/397125
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4715000/397125

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen thank you for this ! am self studying set theory and have more than once thought of abandoning the idea, but timely help from this community has really encouraged me to continue

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, just one last question, in the Hamkins and Seabold paper, the name for the generic set is the boolean ultrapower . Is this the same approach to my last paragraph above ? i.e. construct a boolean valued model $M^B$ then pick any ultrafilter $H \in B$ to create a model $M[H]$ for which the name of the generic set is $H$ ?

Comment: @LinkL No I think you're confused on this point (how can a generic set be embedded if it doesn't exist?). We can certainly quotient down to a two-valued model $V^B/H$ using an arbitrary ultrafilter $H,$ but what is generic is not $H$ but rather $[\dot G]_H$ is generic (over the Boolean ultrapower $\check V_H$). In the case where $H$ is actually generic, we have $[\dot G]_H = H$, $\check V_H= V$ and $V^B/H = V[H]$ (after identifying $V^B/H$ with its Mostowski collapse).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, thank you, sorry for being impertinent, but is it true then that for the quotient downed model $V^B/H$ for an arbitrary ultrafilter $H$, we have that some $[\dot{G}]_H$ always exists ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151965/discussion-between-link-l-and-spaceisdarkgreen).

Answer (score 2):

You have the following formulation of the Baire Category Theorem:

Let $(P,<)$ be a partially ordered set.  Let $\{D_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be subsets of $P$ each with the following property

- For all $p\in P$ there exists a $d\in D_n$ and $r\in P$ such that $r\le p$ and $r\le d$. $(*)$

and let $x\in P$.  Then there exists a filter $G$ on $P$ such that $x\in G$ and $G\cap D_n\ne\emptyset$ for all $n$.

The proof uses the axiom of dependent choice (and I believe is known to be equivalent to it.)  It goes as follows

- There exists a $d_1\in D_1$ and $r_1\in P$ such that $r_1\le x\land r_1\le d_1$.
- There exists a $d_2\in D_2$ and $r_2\in P$ such that $r_2\le r_1\land r_2\le d_2$.
- There exists a $d_3\in D_3$ and $r_3\in P$ such that $r_3\le r_2\land r_3\le d_3$.

and so on by induction $d_n, r_n$ for all $n$.  Since $\{r_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a descending sequence, it's a filter base.  Let $G=\{p\in P\colon \exists n \,r_n\le p\}$.  Then $G$ is a filter, $x\in G$ and $d_n\in G$ for all $n$, hence $G\cap D_n\ne\emptyset$ for all $n$.  This completes the proof.

Now, as I understand, the reason for using a **countable** ground model $M$ is because then $M$ has only countably many sets, so it has only countably many sets $D$ satisfying the condition $(*)$ (which Jech calls 'predense'), so working in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, the theorem guarantees the existence of a filter $G$.